# XNA sprite movement gone wrong

Tags: c#, xna, 2d

Hy everyone, so first off all, here is the image of my sprite:
[image]

I scaled it down in my game so its not that big in-game.

So anyway my desired result of the code below:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        spritePos = spriteVelocity + spritePos;
        spriteR = new Rectangle((int)spritePos.X, (int)spritePos.Y, spriteT.Width, spriteT.Height);
        spriteOrigin = new Vector2(spriteR.Width/2, spriteR.Height / 2);

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) rotation += 0.1f;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) rotation -= 0.1f;

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            spriteVelocity.X = (float)Math.Cos(rotation) * tangentialVelocity;
            spriteVelocity.Y = (float)Math.Sin(rotation) * tangentialVelocity;
        } else if (spriteVelocity != Vector2.Zero)
        {
            float i = spriteVelocity.X;
            float j = spriteVelocity.Y;

            spriteVelocity.X = i -= friction * i;
            spriteVelocity.Y = j -= friction * j;
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

and then Draw method:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        foreach(Bushes bush in bushes)
        {
            bush.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        player.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.Draw(spriteT, spritePos, null, Color.White, rotation, spriteOrigin, 0.1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

is that when I press 'Up' arrow this little rocket should go into direction in whis it is pointing (becouse I can rotate it with Left and Right arrow to have it pointed where desired), but the result of this code is that when I press Up arrow the sprite moves to the right at first, and when its rotated it doesnt go where its pointed but kinda sideways :/

What am I doing wrong here?

PS. all those variables that arent declared and initialized in code are global variables and initialized in Initialize() and LoadContent() methods :/

Answer (score 0):

If your rotation is initialized at 0, it should point to the right, look at where 0 points at on the trig circle below :)

[image: Trig Circle]

You could compute your direction with [Vector2.Transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464182.aspx) and give as *value* parameter (first) **Vector2(0,1)** so your reference direction would be up.

Or you rotate your sprite to the right and initialize your angle at Pi/2.